# converting datetime to string on Databricks SQL

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql, databricks, databricks-sql

Quite new to Databricks SQL.
So, I need to join 2 tables of 3, and to do that, I need to convert datetime to string, but just dont know how, the query:
OBS: the code is running, but it just shows null results

```
select distinct 
aa.column1,
aa.column2,
cc.column3, 
from table1 aa
left join table3 cc on cc.shift_original_name = aa.shift
join table2 bb on aa.column1 between (cc.start_time) and (cc.end_time)
```

the  `aa.column1` is the `datetime`, and the `cc.start_time`/`cc.endtime` are string.

as im a noobie using SQL, i tried using left join, timestamps, convert, and couldnt do it.

Comment: use to_timestamp to compare which will give you expected result

Answer (score 0):

In spark you have to join on same types. Then either convert the string into timestamp or timestamps into strings. In theory the former is better since ts is smaller data structure than string.

Checkout the string timestamp you have [see java format for more info](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

You will use [to_timestamp(timestamp_str[, fmt])](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.0/sql-ref-functions-builtin.html) or  `date_format(timestamp, fmt)` to convert a string into timestamp.

For eg:

- **ts->string**: `date_format(ts_col, 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss')`
- **string->ts**: `to_timestamp('2021-01-01 01:01:01', 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss')`